# Windows 10 icons missing in the task bar

Tags: window, icons, taskbar

On my laptop with Windows 10, 2 thumbnails are missing in the task bar. The 2 applications are pinned to the taskbar but the thumbnails are not visible.
To be more specific. It's the Edge and Store thumbnails.

[The empty spaces in the task bar show where icons are missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0v78.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. If I understand correctly, you are saying that your Edge and Store thumbnails are not displaying correctly and instead you have a broken thumbnail in place.

You probably just need to rebuild your icon/thumbnail cache. Here is an article on how to do it;

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rebuild-icon-clear-thumbnail-cache-windows-10